# Glassfish JDBC Connection Pool Properties URL and Url parameters

Tags: jdbc, glassfish

when configuring Glassfish JDBC connection pool, there are 'URL' and 'Url' parameters. I wonder what's the purpose of the 'Url' one. My pool works if I configure 'URL' only.
Just curious, why two?

Comment: I don't see two Url parameters in my own configuration. Are you sure you didn't create one of them manually before?

Comment: not sure, but I wouldn't say I did

Answer (score -1):

Just keep only one of them and delete the second.
i prefer "Url" which takes care about java syntax convention (camelCase)